# How do I use runtime variables in client side modules using Nextjs App router?

Tags: javascript, next.js, server-side-rendering

Historically I would have used `next.config` [publicRuntimeConfig](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/next-config-js/runtime-configuration) but this does not appear to be supported using the "app router". There are workarounds for using runtime variables in components because they are accessible on the server - for instance server side rendering a value or using a route handler to return a variable.

How would I get access to these variables in a simple regular module? For example a basic utility function that does something with a runtime variable and returns it. I could maybe initialize it with data returned from the server - this seems overly complex just to read a runtime variable client side. What am I doing wrong?

anything in a component is working ok by either doing SSR and opting out of static optimization or using a route handler and a client side fetch

I've tried initializing a function from a module but the `client` and `server` sides to my understanding are completely isolated.